# c++ fgets format char*

Tags: c++, char, format, fgets

hello beginner in c++ i try to read a output from popen, i put a large memories to line to avoid segmentation fault. Why does it read strangely, it cuts every 6 characters,i would like to have a entire line like 1444121347809; Running scenario ...

```
ostringstream message;
char* line = new char[ 10 * 1024 * 1024 ];
if ((pf = popen(files_to_open, "r")) != NULL) {
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line)-1, pf) != NULL)
{
  message << line;
```

console :
144414

878486

9; Sce

7.235

secon

Thanks

Comment: could you post the entire routine please?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is `sizeof(line)`, this sentece is returning the size of `char *` (8 bytes). In this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *line = new char[100];

    printf( "Size: %02d\n", sizeof(line) );
}
```

The output is..

```
Size: 08
```

I recomend you use a constant, like `MAX_BUFFER = 10 * 1024 * 1024` or something similar.

Good Luck!

PD:

Try with...

```
#define MAX_BUFFER 10*1024*1024

ostringstream message;
char* line = new char[ MAX_BUFFER  ];
if ((pf = popen(files_to_open, "r")) != NULL) {
while (fgets(line, MAX_BUFFER-1, pf) != NULL)
{
  message << line;
```

Comment: i try while (fgets(line, sizeof(MAX_BUFFER) or char* line = new char[ MAX_BUFFER ]; avec  #define MAX_BUFFER = 10*1024*1024 the same false output

Comment: @qsfsdqf It looks like you have not understood his explanation of your problem at all, since neither of those things address the issue. What do you think `sizeof(MAX_BUFFER)` evaluates to?